# What causes udp reception delay?

Tags: network-programming, udp, delay, sendto

I have noticed that when I am sending packets at even intervals from a udp socket, the first packet sent seems to be delayed. For example, if I am sending the packets every 100 ms, I find the delay between receiving the packets to be normally distributed with mean 100ms and average standard deviation of 4, on my network. However, the gap between the receive time for the first and second packets is usually around 10 to 40 ms - as you can see, that's clearly a statistically significant difference, and so my question is, what's causing it?

I'm using the sendto function from C on linux. Someone suggested the delay might be caused by arp resolution preventing the packet from being sent until the destination ip has been converted to a mac address - is this likely? If I restart the sending program the first packet again takes too long though, and the delay is inconsistent - 10 to 40 ms is a pretty big range.

I need to find out why this first packet is taking too long, and how to work around it.

Edit: Further analysis with pcap indicates that the sending program is sending the packets at the right interval. Problem must be with the receiver, which is using select() to wait for a readable socket, then calling recvfrom and printing the packet. Is there some sort of buffering going on there I might not know about?

Comment: You can use a sniffer to check if its something related to your computer of something related with the transmission of the packet.

Comment: Hey, could whoever downvoted please post why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked about workarounds.  One possible workaround, if the reception time of the packet is important to know, is to set the `SO_TIMESTAMP` socket option.  This will allow you to obtain the time that each packet was received by the destination kernel - you can then use this time in subsequent processing rather than the "current time".

Alternatively, you could have the sender include a high resolution timestamp in the packet that it sends, and use those.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely the time required for the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) address resolution. This is the protocol which resolves MAC addresses to IP addresses.

For working around this, try using static entries in the arp cache with `arp -s ip-address hw_address`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - arp command is not available. `-sh: arp: not found`. Good suggestion though.

Comment: For me its part of the package "net-tools" (like ifconfig etc) and in /sbin/arp. Its a very basic tool which is on almost every distribution, what do you have?

Comment: I have BusyBox v1.7.2 (2010-11-17 12:19:56 GMT) built-in shell (ash)

Comment: can't open '/proc/dev/arp': No such file or directory. There is a /dev, but not /proc/dev or dev/arp. Haven't tried the ioctl yet, as I'd rather not have to use a static arp anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Speculation will get us nowhere, fire up [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and it will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: I'm running a really stripped down system, nothing on it except for ash and my program, and I've been having difficulty getting pcap running. Wireshark is right out.

Comment: If wireshark is out, what about tcpdump? If this does not work, if you can get you hands on a ethernet hub (as opposed to a switch), you should be able to sniff the network remotely.

Comment: Yes - I managed to get this working finally, and it seems the packets are being sent with the correct gap between them; the delay must be on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a single LAN? If so, it is (probably) down to ARP and/or hostname resolution. If it's across a larger network, it may be anything (although probbaly related to route lookup and cache population).

Comment: Yes, single lan. two machines and a dhcp server connected via switch.

Comment: Unlikely to be arp, because I determined that the packets are being sent in proper sequence, and because I'm sure the arp cache must last longer than a couple of seconds.

Comment: @benubird ARP cache retention is OS-dependent. Looking at your last comment on the wireshark recommendation, it seems to be something in the switch fabric causing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough "reputation" to vote up what I consider to be the best solution, so I'll just say that the guy who mentions ARP messages is most-likely right.  I think the ARP messages should only apply on the lan.  They'll show up on wireshark as a "who has 192.168.0.24?" for example... and then there will be a reply from any host that claims to have that IP address.  The initial packet send via UDP to this address has to get an ARP response to resolve the IP address into an Ethernet MAC address... so UDP, on the surface may seem like it should never BLOCK... however this is only true once the ARP address is resolved.  I'm not sure, but I think if you're sending UDP to an address that is not on the LAN, it shouldn't require an ARP... unless there's a problem finding the primary gateway.